# How can I compare two ByteArrays inside FunctionCompile in 13.3

Tags: data-types, function-compile, version-13.3

I need a compiled function that takes an array of bytes as input and in the process compares parts of that array. It's really just looking for the occurrence of one array in another. It works if you use the existing pre-13.3 functionality - i.e. specify an array of unsigned integers as an argument type instead of an array of bytes. But as I guess - during call the byte array is converted to array of integers, and it takes time. I wanted to avoid that directly by specifying an array of bytes in the function signature. However, the comparison function for the byte array is not defined inside the compiled code. How can I compare two byte arrays as quickly as possible?

My old code contains something like this:

```
f2 = FunctionCompile[Function[{
    Typed[ba1, "NumericArray"::["UnsignedInteger8", 1]], 
    Typed[ba2, "NumericArray"::["UnsignedInteger8", 1]]
}, 
    {ba1 == ba2, ba1 === ba2}
]]
```

[image: previous version]

The same code I wanted to update for version 13.3:

```
f1 = FunctionCompile[Function[{
    Typed[ba1, "ByteArray"], 
    Typed[ba2, "ByteArray"]
}, 
    {ba1 == ba2, ba1 === ba2}
]]
```

[image: new version]

Comment: Benchmark shows `f2[ba1, ba2]` is actually quite fast. I guess, although _"during call the byte array is converted to array of integers, and it takes time"_, at the low level no large data copy happens, so the "convert" might just be a matter of bit-casting a pointer.

Comment: In system file `SystemFiles\Components\Compile\TypeSystem\Declarations\SpecificTypes\ByteArray\ByteArrayBase.m` there is a function called `asNumericArray`, which I suppose should convert a `"ByteArray"` to a `"NumericArray"["UnsignedInteger8", 1]` very efficiently. I compared it with your `f2` and saw no significant performance difference.

Comment: @Silvia how can I use this function inside FunctionCompile?

Comment: My experiences were all based on speculation and test, so please take it with a grain of salt. As it looks like `asNumericArray` is declared with `FunctionDeclaration`, I assumed it follows the official documentation, so, as any built-in functions, I tried using `asNumericArray` directly in code inside `FunctionCompile` and it worked. (Of course, the type `Typed[ {"ByteArray"} -> "NumericArray"["UnsignedInteger8", 1] ]` must be matched.)

Comment: A most simplest example would be: `FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[ba, "ByteArray"], Compile'TypeSystem'Declarations'SpecificTypes'ByteArray'ByteArrayBase'asNumericArray[ba]]]` (Sorry for the backticks, not sure how to properly format them in comment.)